# Facebook share button not showing up

Tags: javascript, facebook

I try to get a share button using the official documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

I have to do 2 steps:

> 1. Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening  tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

> 2. Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="icon"></div>
```

However, nothing shows up. Why is that?

http://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/whhn6b0k/

Comment: `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to set the 'domain' property on 'Document': Assignment is forbidden for sandboxed iframes.` You tried it locally or only in jsfiddle?

Comment: I tried it on my ftp. Where can I see the error you got in jsfiddle? If I open the developer console in chrome I see no errors at all.

Comment: hmm strange, I just tested in safari to see If I get an error there but I get the  share button there... I'm lost... (chrome sucks those days)

Comment: i see that on jsfiddle.

Comment: Can you link to a page where we can see the Share button not showing up? The errors in JSFiddle seem particular to JSFiddle.

Comment: I know what it was now. The browser I tested on had a extension installed to remove things like facebook...